# Is heat always associated with Light?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light

I have found that light always produces heat. The only cases I think heat is absent with light is [Fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence) and [Phosphorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorescence) (maybe because they emit low energy but maybe the heat is still present?). So my question is: Is heat energy always present when light is emitted, specially for bright light(more energy)?

If some example or any links can be provided, then it will be very helpful.

Comment: Light does not produce heat.  It is the _absorption_ of light that produces heat.  Light is energy.  Heat is energy.  When a physical body absorbs light, it converts the energy of the absorbed photons into kinetic energy (vibrations) of its own atoms.  We call that mechanical energy "heat".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thermal radiation is emitted by any surface having a temperature higher than absolute zero. So the short answer to your question is yes. Light (electromagnetic radiation) of any frequency will heat surfaces that absorb it. In case of Fluorescence, the emitted light has a longer wavelength (lower frequency), and therefore lower energy, so that's why you feel the heat is absent.

Comment: So basically light absorbed by any body will raise its temperature even if by a minuscules amount, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: If i correctly understand this it also means that any source of light will have a raise in temperature.

Comment: In photometry, there is something called luminous efficiency. It is simply a ratio between the power emitted in region of visible light to the required power of a light source. Practically, this ratio is always less than one, so there is always some amount of power that ends up as heat instead of light. So yes, even a very efficient light source will still have a raise in temperature. An incandescent lamp is well known example of a low efficiency light source.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sort of duplicate answer here [Heat into light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129363/how-can-heat-turn-into-light?rq=1) and perhaps by reading it, you might get a better picture of how the spread of electromagnetic frequencies process works.

I am not sure that it answers your question directly however, so hopefully this answer, or a better one that comes later, will fill in any blanks.

When visible light is produced, there is always some probability, and it can be an extremely small probability, because of the quantum nature of electromagnetic radiation,  that you will also receive photons from the lower end of the spectrum, that is, in this particular case, infra red radiation (heat).

Whether you can actually detect this heat depends on how sensitive your measuring apparatus is, and also at what wavelength the light source is designed to emit radiation at.

> Is heat energy always present when light is emitted, specially for bright light (more energy)?

So if a lamp is designed to produce mainly ultraviolet light, there is less chance of infrared heat, at the other end of the visible light spectrum, being produced, but if  the light is mainly designed for light energy levels closer to infrared, then there may be a greater probability of stray infred red heat radiation being produced.

Finally, LED lamps, as you probably know, operate at cooler temperatures than old fashioned incandescent bulbs, as demonstrated in this link: [LED Lamps](http://eartheasy.com/live_energyeff_lighting.htm)

The diagram below shows how infra red radiation comes at the lower energy end of the visible light section of the e-m spectrum.

EDIT: Abanob extends my answer and corrects my assumption that only the visible light range is involved in this post. Also see James's comments on lasers, which are very efficient. END

[image]

Comment: You seem to associate heat with infrared radiation only, which is incorrect. Any electromagnetic radiation of any wavelength can become heat provided that it is absorbed by a material. Radiation in the infrared part of the spectrum is easily absorbed by many materials, and that's why we popularly  treat it as heat.

Comment: If a beam of bright light feels warm because "there is always some probability [...] that you will also receive photons from the lower end of the spectrum", then you ought to feel safe standing in front of a high-powered visible-wavelength laser because, for a laser, that "probability" is _very_, _very_ small.

Comment: @jameslarge And I **do** feel very safe, as I stay away from lasers as much as poss. Only a speed cop hit me with one last month. $100 fine. Point taken though, it's difficult to get balance right for OP based on post content. Regards

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different take on your question with  more emphasis on the thermodynamics of light.

If the body emitting light has a well defined temperature and optionally the electronic charges in the material have a well defined chemical potential. The emitted light can be represented as a photon gas which has related thermodynamic properties just like an ideal gas (temperature, internal energy, entropy, chemical potential etc). So on some level **all** equilibrium light can be thought of as a heat flow.

For more information read, The chemical potential of radiation, P. Würfel.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the already given answers, be reminded that heat and light are from two different categories.

- Light is an energy form.
- Heat is an energy *transformation*.

Asking if kinetic energy and work are the same will of the same reason be odd. A body can have kinetic energy, but it cannot "have" work. Work is not an energy form, it is an energy transformation. Similarly, light is energy "packages" travelling, which can *heat up* something at impact, transforming or transferring the energy into or to something else.